# Custom Validations Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

I have a contact form and would like to show individual messages depending on what has failed.I would like to use flash messages. So from what i have read so far i can create a custom method (or i think it just overrides the one in place?)

So for example, i want to validate the presence of the name field

```
Class Message

attr_accessor :name
validates :name, :presence => true

def validate
 if self.name < 0
  errors.add(:name, "Name cannot be blank")
 end
end
end
```

Within my controller i normally use a generic message

```
flash.now.alert = "Please Ensure all Fields are filled in"
```

Is there a way to call the particular message that failed validation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin available, u can follow the below url

```
https://github.com/jeremydurham/custom-err-msg
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the method [validates](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates) because you can pass a message argument with the desired message.

```
validates :name, :presence => {:message => 'The name can't be blank.'}
```

Comment: how would i display the message in a flash alert?

Comment: @Richlewis Check this [application](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan) for an example. So you have the full application if you have any doubt.